# Time picker Now button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a table

```
<table id="tbl1">
    <tr class="Row">
        <td class="TimeCol">
            <input title="" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="FromTime " />
        </td>
        <td class="TimeCol">
            <input title="" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ToTime " />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and i've an anchor tag on which i add new rows to table like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:return AddRow();">
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.FromTime, .ToTime').timepicker({
            timeFormat: "H:m:s",
            stepMinute: 01,
            ampm: true
        });
});
    function AddRow() {
        var $ttc = '';

        $ttc = $("#tbl1").find("tr:last");

        var $tr = $ttc.clone();

        // reset fields in the new row
        $tr.find("input[type=text]").val("");
        $tr.find(".FromTime").removeAttr('value');
        $tr.find(".ToTime").removeAttr('value');

        // add cloned row as last row
        $('#tbl1 tr:last').after($tr);


        // re-initialise the cloned timepickers:
        $fromTimepicker = $('#tbl1 tr:last').find('.FromTime,.ToTime');
        $fromTimepicker.removeClass("hasDatepicker");
        $fromTimepicker.timepicker({
            timeFormat: "H:m:s",
            stepMinute: 01,
            ampm: true
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Now when the new row is added and I click on `Now` button of timepicker, time is updated in the first row textbox... what is the problem and how it can be resolved?

**Before Now click Image**

[image]

**After Now click Image**

[image]

**Update**
If i add timepicker to textbox using id then no timepicker is added

```
var fromId = $('#tbl1 tr:last').find('.FromTime').attr('id');
$('#'+fromId).removeClass("hasDatepicker");
$('#' + fromId).timepicker({
    timeFormat: "H:m:s",
    stepMinute: 01,
    ampm: true
});
```

Comment: Isn't the Now button disabled?

Comment: No..It might look like that but its not

Comment: ...any demo to play with?

Comment: which timepicker plugin do you use?

Comment: I'm using `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`

Comment: Is this line correct `$('#tblAvaiability tr:last').after($tr);`? Cant see an element with that ID. If it is correct then `$('#tbl1 tr:last').find('.FromTime,.ToTime');` is always getting the original controls over and over again

Comment: @StephenMuecke: that works for me and i also tried this `$tr.appendTo($("#tbl1 "));` but still problem is not solved

Comment: @StephenMuecke : if you are talking about `#tblAvaiability`, it was a typo.

Comment: I'm not sure what `$fromTimepicker.removeClass("hasDatepicker");` is doing (can't see any where you have added that class, and what's it for?). You are cloning the row but have not removed the current instance of the `timepicker` attached to it. I don't know the plugin you are using but it should have a `remove` or `destroy` function. In any case I suggest you create the row from scratch rather than cloning an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I added removed `id` attribute and everything works fine.

I added this  `$fromTimepicker.removeAttr("id");` before initializing time picker like this

```
    $fromTimepicker = $('#tbl1 tr:last').find('.FromTime,.ToTime');
    $fromTimepicker.removeClass("hasDatepicker");
    $fromTimepicker.removeAttr("id");
    $fromTimepicker.timepicker({
        timeFormat: "H:m:s",
        stepMinute: 01,
        ampm: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize, timepicker on element ID rather than element class.
When you clone a row to add a new row, the new row has the same class as the previous row. Since when you click on "Now" button on the timepicker widget, the timepicker uses class to select the input field and updates the time in the first input field it finds, which is the time field in the first row.

If you use unique ID on each input element, timepicker will update time in the correct element.

EDIT:
Try the following change:

```
// re-initialise the cloned timepickers:
$('#tbl1 tr:last').find('.FromTime').attr('id', 'new_from').removeClass("hasDatepicker"); 
$('#tbl1 tr:last').find('.ToTime').attr('id', 'new_to').removeClass("hasDatepicker"); 
$('#new_from, #new_to').timepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
    stepMinute: 01,
    ampm: true
});
```

Comment: but i specified to apply timpicker to last row in this line
`$fromTimepicker = $('#tbl1 tr:last').find('.FromTime,.ToTime');`

Comment: The problem is $('.FromTime, .ToTime').timepicker(...). You are initializing timepicker on inputs having 'FromTime' or 'ToTime' class. If you have more than one row, you'll have multiple elements having the above mentioned classes.

Comment: ok but timepicker is not added even if i add it using id, please check the updated code.

Comment: You are trying to take the ID from original input fields. Since your original fields do not have any ID defined, timepicker fails to bind to any input. You can share your entire html page code and I'll be able to you.